# How to get color from slice index?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, pie-chart

I implemented `corePlot` in my `xcode` project. I know there is a way to fill the pie slices color:

```
-(CPTFill *)sliceFillForPieChart:(CPTPieChart *)pieChart recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
```

But is there a way to get what color the `index's` slice is?

Example:

[image]

If I try getting index's 0 color, it would be blue, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you fill out the DataSource function to provide the color, which means you already have the color.
For you case, I think you could use this function:

`+ (CPTColor *) defaultPieSliceColorForIndex:(NSUInteger) pieSliceIndex`

The doc is [here](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/interface_c_p_t_pie_chart.html#ad2efbb8005aebd12a9801a54edacf1ea).

To get the UIColor of CPTColor, simply get the CPTColor's property uiColor. Detailed information is available on [Doc](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/interface_c_p_t_color.html#a47cd72bec7f2ba5ae09e6c6c143e9e9e).

Comment: Can I convert a `CPTColor` to a `UIColor`?